# How do I preserve the line ordering for two "equal" strings while sorting and ignoring the case?

Tags: command-line, sort

The contents of `fred` is:

```
START
test
TEST
tEST
END
```

From the bash terminal, `sort fred` returns:

```
END
START
test
tEST
TEST
```

All good. Now I type `sort fred -f` with the same result for `sort fred`. But because `TEST` is ahead of `tEST`, the expected result was:

```
END
START
test
TEST
tEST
```

How do I preserve the line ordering for two "equal" strings? Using Ubuntu 18.04 and bash 4.4.20(1)-release.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you mean [Stable sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts). [`sort`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) command does have a flag `-s` which does stable sort.

Snippet from [`sort` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html):

> **-s, --stable**
>                       stabilize sort by disabling last-resort comparison

Output of `sort fred -f`:

```
END
START
test
tEST
TEST
```

Output of `sort fred -fs`:

```
END
START
test
TEST
tEST
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the `-s` option too:

```bash
sort -fs fred
```

You had passed `-f` to make the sort case-insensitive, but since you want to preserve the original order of lines that compare the same, you need the `-s` option as well. This produces the output you're looking for.

```bash
ek@Cord:~$ sort -f fred  # without -s
END
START
TEST
tEST
test
ek@Cord:~$ sort -fs fred  # with -s
END
START
test
TEST
tEST
```

As for why this is needed:

- One might say that the abstract, high-level reason is that [not all sorting algorithms are stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability).
- In the `sort` command, the specific reason is that, when two keys are equal, a [**last resort comparison**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64104/11938) of the whole line is performed. *That* comparison doesn't fold case, even when `-f` is passed.